# Connecting four points with drawContours in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector of 4 points:

```
vector<vector<Point> > data(4);
data[0].push_back(Point(0,0));
data[1].push_back(Point(0,120));
data[2].push_back(Point(180,100));
data[3].push_back(Point(70,0));
```

I want to connect them and draw the shape on the image.
I tried using drawContours function, but this code didn't work:

```
for( int i = 0; i< data.size(); i++ )
     {
       drawContours(input,data,i,Scalar(0,255,0),10,LINE_8);
     }
```

Comment: What does *"code didn't work"* mean to you?  Did it draw something?  Nothing?  Did the code compile?

Comment: It draws only these points without a line between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'data' contains 4 contours. Each contour has one point that was drawn on image. What you need is 1 contour with 4 points. Push all your points to data[0].

On side note, you don't need to call drawContours() in loop. If you provide negative index of contour (third parameter), then all contours will be drawn.

```
vector<vector<Point> > data(1);
data[0].push_back(Point(0,0));
data[0].push_back(Point(0,120));
data[0].push_back(Point(180,100));
data[0].push_back(Point(70,0));
drawContours(input, data, -1, Scalar(0,255,0), 10, LINE_8);
```

Comment: after you draw the contours, how do you get the all the contours and store them, of what you just drew, while ignoring everything else in the image?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 4 points, I suggest you to use cv::Rectangle. If you can have a lot of points, you have to write a function using [cv::Line](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line).